# Send email when a particular value is 0

Tags: google-apps-script

I am making a project planner which is sending mails when a particular task is not complete. I am assigning done/not done column 0(not done)/1(Done). 
[Open this image to have a look on table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/71Yl6.png)

```
     function checkReminder() {
   // get the spreadsheet object
 var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 // set the first sheet as active
 SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheets()[0]);
 // fetch this sheet
var sheet = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet();

// figure out what the last row is
var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();

// the rows are indexed starting at 1, and the first row
// is the headers, so start with row 11
var startRow = 11;

// grab column 5 (the 'done/not done' column) 
var range = sheet.getRange(11,5,lastRow-startRow,1 );
var numRows = range.getNumRows();
var done_notdone_values = range.getValues();

// Now, grab the reminder name column
range = sheet.getRange(11, 11, lastRow-startRow, 1);
var reminder_info_values = range.getValues();

var warning_count = 0;
var msg = "";

// Loop over the done value values
for (var i = 0; i <= numRows - 1; i++) {
var binary = done_notdone_values[i][0];
if(binary == 0) {
  // if it's exactly 0, do something with the data.
  var reminder_name = reminder_info_values[i][0];

  msg = msg + "->"+reminder_name + " \r\n";
  warning_count++;
}
}

 if(warning_count) {
MailApp.sendEmail("xyz@.com", 
                  "Reminder CCUFC4", msg,{ cc:"abc@gmail.com"});
}

};
```

But I am getting mail in this format. I want one point in one single line with serial number. How to get this. What can be done?
[Mail image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CKJXI.png)

Answer (score 1):

It is because the sendEmail line is outside the loop so till the time, the loop is finished the **var msg** keeps on getting appended and then when it comes out of the loop, the value of the **var warning_count** is **3** and thus it sending the email the way you have shared in the image.

Please try the code given below and it should work just fine:

```
    // figure out what the last row is
    var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();

    // the rows are indexed starting at 1, and the first row
    // is the headers, so start with row 11
    var startRow = 11;

    // grab column 5 (the 'done/not done' column) 
    var range = sheet.getRange(11,5,lastRow-startRow,1 );
    var numRows = range.getNumRows();
    var done_notdone_values = range.getValues();

    // Now, grab the reminder name column
    range = sheet.getRange(11, 11, lastRow-startRow, 1);
    var reminder_info_values = range.getValues();

    var warning_count;
    var msg = "";

    // Loop over the done value values
    for (var i = 0; i <= numRows - 1; i++) {
warning_count = 0;// resetting the flag as zero for new row every time
    var binary = done_notdone_values[i][0];
    if(binary == 0) {
      // if it's exactly 0, do something with the data.
      var reminder_name = reminder_info_values[i][0];

      msg = msg + "->"+reminder_name + " \r\n";
      warning_count++;
    }
//moved the condition inside the loop
if(warning_count) {
    MailApp.sendEmail("xyz@.com", 
                      "Reminder CCUFC4", msg,{ cc:"abc@gmail.com"});
    }
    }

    };
```

Comment: if I put this into loop then it will send mail many times. What I want is to change the format of mail i.e send all info in one mail and each point in single line not in two lines